# Using IF function within QUERY formulas (Google Sheet)

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

all.

I'm working on a stacked bar chart showing my trading P/L, with the green bars showing gains while the red bars showing losses. But as you can see in the image (attached), the data labels for the red bars show up on the RH side if it's $0, which I want to get rid of. I figured I should use an IF formula within the query formula (on cell G1) so that the if a cell returns "$0.00", it should remain an empty cell. However, after a few trials, I still couldn't get it to work. I appreciate anyone who can take a look at my spreadsheet (linked below) and see what's the best solution for this. Sheet 2 is editable.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YzuJGVDJ7rZ7PTkJpJCHA27QUiMqXQnP6dI_ZplYWG0/edit?usp=sharing

[Image: Stacked Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqhLe.png)

Thanks!
J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible by using the customized number format

Naviagtion : - **Data Ranage >>Customized>>Number Format>>Other Custom Formats**

Use - **#,##.##**

[image]